# Searching multiple tables in query

Tags: php, sql

```
SELECT  DISTINCT business.name AS businessname
        ,business.description AS description
FROM    business
        , category
        , sub_categories 
WHERE   business.cityID = '$city' 
        AND (category.name LIKE '%$name%' 
             OR sub_categories.name LIKE '%$name%')
        AND business.status = 0
```

Pls the above SQL code is suppose to search a set of two tables the ones in the bracket and return the result, but for some reason, it's not doing so. What am i doing wrong?

Thank You.

Comment: What's it doing instead? Any errors? Different results?

Comment: @deceze It's returning by default 5 results. Without the distinct keyword it returns every record that matches the city against return things that corresponds with the city and their specific categories or sub categories. @Haim Evgi, will do so. Thanks

Comment: cityID is probably a number. If so dont enclode '$city' in quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query would produce a [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). Depending on the size of your tables that could take a considerable amount of time.

Based on your clarification I'd use a subquery to check for matching categories, this way you don't have to use distinct in your query as it would only return each business once. I also suggest you to start with a decent SQL tutorial.

```
SELECT  name AS businessname
       ,description AS description
FROM    business
WHERE   cityID = '$city' 
AND     status = 0
AND (   categoryID in (select id from category where name like '%$name%') 
    or  subcategoryID in (select id from sub_categories where name like '%$name%')
)
```

Comment: @Martin, the business table has the category ID and sub categories ID on other words they are all foreign keys on the business table. The aim of the query is to get the business name and it's description based on the city ID and the Category or sub category that was input.

Comment: SELECT  business.name AS businessname,
 business.description AS description
    FROM    business
    WHERE   business.cityID = 1
    AND     `status` = 0
    AND (   business.catID in (select id from category where `name` like '%Hotels%') 
    or  business.subCatID in (select id from sub_categories where `name` like '%$Hotels%')
), but it's not returning any result.

Comment: You just did. It's the checkmark icon below the vote count. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind:

1. You are not joining any of the three tables together.  Consider adding a few LEFT JOIN clauses.
2. You are selecting columns from only one table.  If you wanted columns from other tables, you should add them to your SELECT clause.

Comment: thanks for your responds, pls can you format the sql in the right way for me. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, the right way the code is code is suppose to be written, with the JOIN's and all. Here is the relationship; the business table has the category ID and sub categories ID on other words they are all foreign keys on the business table. The aim of the query is to get the business name and it's description based on the city ID and the Category or sub category that was input